# QTableView inside QTabWidget does not show data

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, qtableview, qtabwidget

I have a QTabWidget, each tab contains a QTableView.
The tableviews use QTableModels which reads data from an sqlite database.

The models are kept as member variables, so I don't think it's a scope problem (which is the most frequent problem I've found by searching for the issue).

Other db operations works: I tried populating / creating tables in the code, and those operation are correctly executed.

The following is the class definition:

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtSql>
#include <QString>

namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

class AlisnagMainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit AlisnagMainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~AlisnagMainWindow();

protected:
    bool createDB(const QString& filename);
    bool loadDB(const QString& filename);

protected slots:
    void newFile();
    void openFile();
    void addRow();

private:
    void initModels();
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QSqlDatabase db;
    QSqlRelationalTableModel    *loans_model;
    QSqlTableModel              *people_model;
    QSqlRelationalTableModel    *items_model;
};
```

This is the constructor:

```
AlisnagMainWindow::AlisnagMainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow),
    loans_model( new QSqlRelationalTableModel(this) ),
    people_model( new QSqlTableModel(this) ),
    items_model( new QSqlRelationalTableModel(this) )
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");

    connect(ui->actionNew,  SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(newFile()));
    connect(ui->actionOpen, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(openFile()));
}
```

This is how I initialized the models and the views:

```
void AlisnagMainWindow::initModels(){
    people_model->setTable("people");
    people_model->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnRowChange);
    people_model->select();
    people_model->setHeaderData(0, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Name"));
    people_model->setHeaderData(1, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Surname"));
    people_model->setHeaderData(2, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Phone"));
    people_model->setHeaderData(3, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Address"));

    items_model->setTable("items");
    items_model->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnRowChange);
    items_model->setRelation(3, QSqlRelation("categories","id","name"));
    items_model->select();

    loans_model->setTable("loans");
    loans_model->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnRowChange);
    loans_model->setRelation(0, QSqlRelation("items","id","name"));
    loans_model->setRelation(1, QSqlRelation("people","id","name"));
    loans_model->select();

    ui->peopleView->setModel(people_model);
    ui->peopleView->hideColumn(0);

    ui->itemsView->setModel(items_model);
    ui->itemsView->hideColumn(0);

    ui->loansView->setModel(loans_model);
    ui->loansView->hideColumn(0);

}
```

The database is loaded as follows:

```
bool AlisnagMainWindow::loadDB(const QString &filename)
{
    if(db.isOpen())
        db.close();
    db.setDatabaseName(filename);

    if( !db.open() ){
        QMessageBox::critical(this, tr("Error"),
                              tr("Could not open db %1").arg(filename),
                              QMessageBox::Ok);
        return false;
    }

    ui->statusBar->showMessage("DB successfully opened!");
    return true;

}
```

Then this is how is all combined:

```
void AlisnagMainWindow::openFile()
{
    QString filename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Choose DB file"),
                                                    ".", "*.db");
    loadDB(filename);

    initModels();
}
```

The file I'm opening has been populated externally. When I run the code, neither the data nor the headers are shown. Any insight?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Added some context as requested

Comment: Incomplete information. If you want people to help you debug, don't just throw in some context less functions from which **you think** they might contain the problem.

Comment: To be honest that's pretty everything I have so far, the only thing I didn't put here is the constructor and the class definition. The former initialize the member variables, nothing more nothing less. The latter contains just the members definitions, as it should.

 Anyway, sorry if it's not detailed enough: until now I've never needed direct help, I've always found solutions by searching, so this is the first time I directly post for help.

Comment: Looks much better now. So, I am not sure about this part, but worth a try. You create your model: loans_model( new QSqlRelationalTableModel(this) ). According to doc: If you don't provide db in second param, the default db is used. But what default db? You add the db later in the constructor. I don't think (speculation) that this magically is passed retroactively to your models... So your models probably don't work on your sqlite db.

Comment: I will "play" with the initializations, either I solve the problem and modify the post or come back for help.

Thank you for the insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Greenflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2011734/greenflow) pointed out, problem was in the constructor, in particular in the order of initialization.
The constructor is modified as follows

```
AlisnagMainWindow::AlisnagMainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow),
    db ( QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE")),
    loans_model( new QSqlRelationalTableModel(this, db) ),
    people_model( new QSqlTableModel(this, db) ),
    items_model( new QSqlRelationalTableModel(this, db) )
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->actionNew,  SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(newFile()));
    connect(ui->actionOpen, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(openFile()));
}
```

Comment: you should accept this answer to make it clear that your problem is solved